# Arduino Sketch compiles and then freezes upon uploading

Tags: c++, class, arduino, adk

I am currently working on developing an automated checkers board. I've coded it in C++ using three classes and then made the necessary changes to use it as a library on Arduino.
The C++ code is divided into three classes that initiate an 8 by 8 array for the positions of the board and tracks the movement of the pawns on that board.

I think that the conversion to an Arduino library is correct as I am able to compile the sketch without any errors. But when I upload it to the ADK Mega there is absolutely no response on the serial monitor for even simple commands such as `Serial.print()`.

This is the sketch:

```
#include <Board.h>

Board myBoard ;

int currentTurn=0;
int order[4][4]={{0,2,1,3},{1,5,2,4},{4,2,5,3},{2,4,0,2}};
int k=0;    
int *A;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  A=myBoard.arr(); 
  for (int i=0; i<98; i++)
  {
     Serial.print(A[i]);
  }

 command[0]=order[k][0]; 
 command[1]=order[k][1];
 command[2]=order[k][2];
 command[3]=order[k][3];

  myBoard.processCommand(command,currentTurn); 

  if(myBoard.nextTurn())
  {
    if(currentTurn==0)
    { 
      currentTurn=1; 
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      delay(3000);
    }
    else
    { 
      currentTurn=0;
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
      delay(3000);    
    }      
  }
k++;
}
```

Basically, the class returns an array of 0's and 1's that has information about the position of the pawns. But as soon as I upload the sketch nothing happens!

Does anyone have an idea as to why could this be happening?

This is the constructor of the Board class if someone thinks that the problem might be there

**EDIT**

```
 Board::Board()
{

    bool gameFinished=false;
    bool turnChange=false;
    initBoard();
    initPawns();

}
```

I have changed the constructor to simplify things. The array of objects is now created as a public member in the header: Pawn myPawns[24].
The program now runs correctly and i am able to print the array but only for the first iteration in void loop() after which the array printed correspond to an empty board (no pawns present). 
I suspect that the program isn't correctly accessing the array of Pawns after the first iteration -when the constructor is called-. 
Would dynamically allocating the array of Pawns fix this problem ?

Comment: Does the Arduino work with a more simple sketch which just prints to `Serial`? If so then it's likely that either the `Board` constructor or the array returned by `Board.arr()` is the source of the hang, in which case posting the Board code would be helpful.

Comment: Even before adding the arr() function, the sketch was not uploading.
So it's probably a problem with the constructor.

Comment: Still cant post the constructor as an answer because im new to the site. Will do in 4 hours

Comment: Don't post the constructor as an answer, just edit the question and add it there.

Comment: I added the constructor. Thx for the tip Matthew

Comment: Since the `Board` constructor is non-trivial and calls out to other functions (e.g. `initBoard`) and other constructors (`Pawn::Pawn()`) it would probably be best to post all the code you have (or put it up in pastebin (http://pastebin.com/) and link to it).

Comment: Aren't `board` and `myPawns` members of `Board` (rather than local to the constructor)?

Comment: I added the Board.cpp to pastebin.com you can find it at http://pastebin.com/piNtsVAJ

The function checkIfLegal, checkIfLegalDest and nextHopPossible are long (which is why the code is really long) but it is very repetitive so you wouldn't need to go thru it all

Comment: Martin yes they are and I have created them as class public members in the header file Board.h as following: Pawn *myPawns and int board[8][8]

Comment: Thank you for your help ! The problem was with the initialization of a class pawn member which I manually reinitialized in a separate function.
You can find the project on youtube. Its called Checkoids http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31WiFqVv6XI&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you're asking for quite a lot of stack for a small processor:

- 24 `Pawn`s - however big they are
- 64 `int`s for `board`

How big is a `Pawn` in bytes?

You might run out of stack.  Check out [this thread](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=82772.0) for more discussion on types of memory and how to see if you've run out of stack/heap.  [Another useful page on Arduino memory](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/CorruptArrayVariablesAndMemory)

1224 bytes is quite a lot of the 2048 (IIRC) that's available in total!

Also - are you calling `new` at all - that'll use the heap which is RAM also.

**EDIT:**
Sounds from your comments that you've allocated them *twice*, once in the class and once on the stack inside the function - did you mean to do that?

**More edit:**

Don't allocate things in a header.  `extern` then or prototype them, or put them in the class.  But don't allocate them there!

If you have `Pawn myPawns[24]` inside the class, you don't need to declare it in the constructor.

Comment: I don't know the size of the Pawn itself but when I compile the sketch the size is :
    Binary sketch size: 10152 bytes (of a 258048 byte maximum)
 
So I'm not sure that it is a size problem as i am using the Arduino Mega ADK that has 248KB of usable memory.

Comment: Those elements are allocated on the stack (in RAM, 8KB), not in flash (which is the 248KB).  See here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK

Comment: For the size I went over it each Pawn has 6 variables that are integers and there are 24 pawns for a total of 6*4*24=576 bytes.
There is also the board which has 64 int for a total of 256 bytes.
And the last array has 98 int for a total of 392 bytes.

This adds to 1224 bytes

Comment: myPawns[24] is used create an array of 24 int whereas in the header it only refers to an address. But you were right I can omit the int board[8][8] from the constructor as it is already allocated in the header.

Comment: The discussion in "What is the default stack size for function calls" is for the ATmega -2048 bytes- of ram. I am using the Mega ADK which has 8KB of RAM ! And no i am not using new so i think i am still for from the memory limit.

Comment: I tried not to allocate Pawn in the header but since there are several functions using Pawn variables but without taking them as arguments i am having the error "myPawns was not declared in this scope".
The Pawn myPawns[24] is to initialize the array not to allocate new memory as it points to the address already allocated in the header file.